# Wait until all my ajax functions are done, and then continue the execution for this i used async:false but it's not relative to performance

Tags: javascript

```
validateStepOneChannelData: function(callback)
    {
        var response = {error: false, data: {}};
        var error  = false;
        var action = $("#action").val();

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/verifyEmailAddressByKickBox',
        dataType: "json",
        async:false,
        data: ({email: $("#email").val()}),
        beforeSend:function(){
            $('#next_box1_button').prop('disabled', true).addClass('hy-loading-btn');
            $('#saveChannel').prop('disabled', true).addClass('hy-loading-btn');
        },
        success: function(res) {
                $('#next_box1_button').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('hy-loading-btn');
                $('#saveChannel').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('hy-loading-btn');
                if (res.status == 'F') {
                    error = true;
                    response.data.email = 'Please enter valid email address.';
                }

            }
        });

        if (error)
        {
            response.error = true;
        }

        callback(response);
```

I need to wait until all my ajax functions are done, and then continue the exectution for this i used async:false but it's not relative to performance. It is freezing browser for untill the ajax request.

How we used callback here to get the response first and execute the rest block..

Please advise.

Comment: Synchronous ajax freezes the browser exactly as you describe. That's why it's generally considered a very bad idea.

Comment: Chrome and Firefox don't allow synchronous calls anymore.

Comment: @Pointy yes i got it. Can you describe then how i can user callback here.. our concern is to execute  if (error)
        {
            response.error = true;
        } this block after ajax request success

Comment: Put your generic error block into a function and execute from error condition block.

Comment: @Mouser we tried this but didn't get success. if(error) { response.error = true; } is executed already

Answer (score 0):

This way can help you I'm sure

```
function ajaxCall(url,type,data = {}){

    return $.ajax({

        type:type,
        url:url,
        data:data

    })
}

 ajaxCall("url.php","post", {data:data} ).then(function(r){

    // something what you need to do after ajax

 })
```